# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}-\frac{7}{n^{3/2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I would please like your guidance to find if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}-\frac{7}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ converges or diverges?

I noticed that We have two separate $p$-series and $p<1$, so the conclusion is that the series is divergent?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Exactly. If you separate the two p-series, one is convergent and the other one is divergent. Thus their sum is divergent.

Comment: Note, however, that the argument is not 'separate the series'. The argument should be that if you assume that it converges, it does so absolutely. Then if you add the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{7}{n^{3/2}}$ one should get a convergent series, but you don't. Therefore, the original series is not convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the summands are positive when $n > 7^{6/5} \approx 10.33$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum\frac7{n^{3/2}}$ converges absolutely, it is possible to remove it from the series. This leaves the diverging series $\sum\frac1{n^{2/3}}$, so your series diverges.

Note however that it is not possible to split diverging series though. As a trivial example, $\sum\frac1{n^{2/3}}$ diverges, but $\sum\left(\frac1{n^{2/3}}-\frac1{n^{2/3}}\right)$ converges, as it is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have been given many explanations about the divergence.

If you want more, consider
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}-\frac{7}{n^{3/2}}\right)=H_p^{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}-7 H_p^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.

Using there asymptotics, you have
$$S_p=3 \sqrt[3]{p}+\left(\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-7 \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt p}\right)$$ Using this truncated expression, you will see that $S_p > 0$ when $p > 331$ (in fact, this happens when $p > 292$) and then continues growing.

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%281%2Fn%5E%282%2F3%29-7%2Fn%5E%283%2F2%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+10000) for $p=10^4$ gives $44.040$ while the truncated expression given above leads to $43.899$.

Comment: Might i ask, from where does this $ S_p=3 \sqrt[3]{p}+\left(\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-7 \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt p}\right) $ come from? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this a tad overkill? :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. For sure, it is (on purpose). Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.